# How to wire the results of Elasticsarch into Spring's REST API reponse

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I've developed a REST API entry with Spring which conducts a search in Elasticsearch and now I want to return whatever results ES has found as the response. I don't care about the search results and I don't know the JSON structure in it. I just want to return it back to the client.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{index:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void search(@PathVariable String index, @RequestParam Map allRequestParams, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException
{
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for (Map.Entry entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()) {
        query.should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    SearchResponse results = esClient.prepareSearch("nyc_visionzero")
        .setTypes("logs")
        .setQuery(query)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

    SearchHits hits = results.getHits();
    hits.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
}
```

But the last line has a compile error since the two OutputStreams are not compatible. So my question is, what is the easiest way of wiring the results of Elasticsearch into Spring's response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{index:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void search(@PathVariable String index, @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException
{
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()) {
        query.should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    SearchResponse results = esClient.prepareSearch("nyc_visionzero")
        .setTypes("logs")
        .setQuery(query)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

    SearchHits hits = results.getHits();

    ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder(os);
    results.toXContent(builder, ToXContent.EMPTY_PARAMS);
    builder.close();
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to write to the response outputstream, you can change the signature of your search method to return a String then directly return the result as valid JSON. Something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{index:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@PathVariable String index, @RequestParam Map allRequestParams, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException
{
    BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    for (Map.Entry entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()) {
        query.should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }

    SearchResponse results = esClient.prepareSearch("nyc_visionzero")
        .setTypes("logs")
        .setQuery(query)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

    SearchHits hits = results.getHits();

    // Replacing hits.writeTo(response.getOutputStream()); below
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    SearchHit[] hitsDatas = hits.hits();
    int length = hitsDatas.length;
    builder.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       if (i == length - 1) {
          builder.append(hitsDatas[i].getSourceAsString());
       } else {
          builder.append(hitsDatas[i].getSourceAsString());
          builder.append(",");
       }
    }
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've found a better solution., I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score -1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{index:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> search(@PathVariable String index, @RequestParam Map allRequestParams)
{
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (Map.Entry entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()) {
    query.should(QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}

SearchResponse results = esClient.prepareSearch("nyc_visionzero")
    .setTypes("logs")
    .setQuery(query)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();

SearchHits hits = results.getHits();
return new ResponseEntity<>(hits , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

with ResponseEntity class you can return any response without caring about your result type.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work that way. I think it has some issue with Jackson or something and it leads to some runtime error.